# Is there a way in CXF to disable the SoapCompressed header for debugging purposes?

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I'm watching CXF service traffic using [DonsProxy](http://donsproxy.sourceforge.net/), and the CXF client sends an HTTP header "SoapCompressed":

```
HttpHeadSubscriber starting...
Sender is CLIENT at 127.0.0.1:2680
Packet ID:0-1
POST /yada/yada HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
SoapCompressed: true
Accept-Encoding: gzip,gzip;q=1.0, identity; q=0.5, *;q=0
SOAPAction: ""
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Apache CXF 2.2
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: localhost:9090
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I'd like to turn SoapCompressed off in my dev environment so that I can see the SOAP on the wire.  I've searched Google and grepped the CXF source code, but don't see anything in the docs or code that reference this.  Any idea how to make the client send "SoapCompressed: off" instead, without routing it through Apache HTTPD or the like?  Is there a way to configure it at the CXF client, in other words?

Comment: Could you please put your client code into your question?

Comment: Sorry, not enough of it to be helpful.  I assume you're looking for something that explicitly sets that header?  I was thinking it was buried in Spring or CXF somewhere, but it could be in our framework code, which I can search.

Answer (score 1):

A grep of the CXF codebase doesn't yield "SoapCompressed" at all.  I really don't think it's CXF that is sending that.   The Accept-Encoding thing is also suspect as that is only sent if you enable the GZIP interceptors.   Is it possible that the proxy thing you are using is adding it?

Comment: no, it doesn't add anything, it's a wiretap that only displays what's sent through.  the only thing it modifies on the wiretap is latency or bandwidth limitations.

Comment: and i also grep'd the code before asking.  sadly, it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

The client for org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient has points where you set the headers in a key-value map (Map).  "SoapCompressed", "false".

Comment: Hmm.  The jaxrs stuff is for RESTful services, perhaps there's a SOAP equiv that would work for us.  I'll look around for that.